# Why do these CSV records repeat?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am having problem , records duplicates three times in the MYSQL Database what could be the issue? any ideas?

HTML

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" >
     CSV<input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("_SERVER_","_USER_","_PASSWORD_")
    or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
    $db = mysql_select_db("_DATABASE_", $connection)
    or die ("Couldn't select database");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== FALSE)
    {
    $a = $fileop[0];
    $b = $fileop[1];
    $c = $fileop[2];
    $d = $fileop[3];
    $e = $fileop[4];
    $f = $fileop[5];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO f38uj_zhgooglemaps_markers (title, addresstext,  published, baloon, icontype, mapid) 
    values('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f')");

    }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: so any ideas why records dublicate?..is there problem with the code?

Comment: We cant help you unless we see the real example of CSV.

Comment: http://uimg.in/images/2014/01/13/mZQHb.jpg

Comment: this is the CSV....on uploading I get 6 records instead of 3...

Comment: you may try omitting the read length.
fgetcsv($resource,0,',').
try also while(!feof($handler)) {...}

Comment: could you explain further?

Comment: you run until End Of File, and not limit the fgetcsv to read 1000bytes, if you set to 0 - it will read till the end of the line. In case your problem is in length of a line.

Comment: is the problem lying in..while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== FALSE)...what could be the solution?

Comment: I just previously told you ;-)

Comment: i have done as you said..omit fgetcsv it reads while(($fileop = ($handle,0,",")) !== FALSE)..i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','...Fatal error: Function name must be a string...i am also having a problem in coding with while(!feof($handler)) {...}

Comment: i have tried..while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,0,",")) !== FALSE).but now it cant read

Comment: while(!feof($handler)){$fileop = fgetcsv($handler,0,',');}
you dont need false here, because you verify with FEOF.

Comment: this is how i have added..the page takes too long to submit, i have even restarted the comp...but cant submit..$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

while(!feof($handler)){$fileop = fgetcsv($handler,0,',');}
{
$a = $fileop[0];
$b = $fileop[1];
$c = $fileop[2];

Comment: We can't really help unless we can see at least a sample of your CSV.

Comment: @teampost: the csv image is up there

Comment: @Valentin Rusk: this is very funny i have removed !== FALSE) as in now  while ($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"))...when i upload the csv it doesnt repeat and but when i refresh the page without uploading the CSV, records repeats again..what is this now!!

Comment: any ideas why it keep on repeating

Comment: uimg.in/images/2014/01/13/mZQHb.jpg